# Specifying python version for shebang in CGI scripts run by CGIHTTPServer

Tags: python, cgi

I am running a CGI server using CGIHTTPServer on windows. It executes CGI scripts normally using the default python path. I am aware that I can change the shebang line in the beginning to specify a different python version, however, this doesn't work.

Here is the server code:

```
import socket
import CGIHTTPServer
PORT = 8000
host_name=socket.gethostname()

def run_server(port):
    server_address = ('', PORT)
    handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
    handler.cgi_directories = ['']
    server = CGIHTTPServer.BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, handler)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.socket.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("serving on:",host_name,PORT)

    run_server(PORT)
```

and here is the client code:

```
#!c:/python27/python.exe
import sys

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print sys.version_info
print "OK"
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

and here is the output I get on the server when I open the page/execute the CGI script:

```
WIN7-123.aa.cc - - [06/Oct/2017 11:21:09] command: C:\Python26\python.exe -u C:\test\KM\cgi.py ""
WIN7-123.aa.cc - - [06/Oct/2017 11:21:09] CGI script exited OK
```

also when I print sys.version_info in the page, it gives me this

> (2, 6, 0, 'final', 0) OK

Is there a certain setting in CGIHTTPServer that can be adjusted to allow specifying the python version, or where do you think the problem is?  Thanks!

--EDIT-- 
One additional motivation for this question was to be able to specify a path to a portable python executable in order to run my application (which I compile with pyinstaller) in machines that do not have python

Comment: I don't think Windows processes shebangs. I guess there is a setting somewhere, but as a workaround, you could maybe change your script to `exec()` a different Python interpreter.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, that can be a good work around for now :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell actually one additional motivation for this question was to be able to specify a path to a portable python executable in order to run my application (which I compile with pyinstaller) in machines that do not have python